# How to keep SyncTeX aligned when re-ordering pages using LuaTeX `page_order_index` callback?

Tags: luatex, forward-inverse-search

I'm using the LuaTeX callback `page_order_index` to re-order the PDF pages (specifically, the last page becomes the first and the rest shifts down by one).

This works fine, but the SyncTeX file does not 'follow' this re-ordering: jumping forwards and backwards goes to the right location, but on the wrong page, namely the original page that would've been there.

Is there a way to either:

- Delay SyncTeX generation until after the re-ordering?
- Update the generated SyncTeX file to apply the re-ordering?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You probably have to parse and rewrite the synctex file manually.  You can use the `finish_synctex` callback for that.  The synctex support in LuaTeX is only rudimentary because ConTeXt implements synctex in Lua and doesn't use the one inside the engine.